# What is interior derivative geometrically?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, lie-derivative

The last equality on page $398$ of Jeffrey Lee's Manifold and Differential Geometry textbook states that

$$\int_{M} div(X) \omega = \int_{\partial M} i_{X} \omega,$$ where $M$ is an oriented manifold with boundary $\partial M$,  $\omega$ is a volume form on $M$, and $i_{X}$ is the interior derivative[(definition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product) with respect to a given smooth vector field $X.$

Note that its proof is a direct consequence of the definition of Lie derivative[(definition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative), Cartan's magic formula, and "generalized" Stoke's theorem on forms [(statement can be found here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem). I have a clear understanding of the proof. However, the author comments that this formula helps give a geometric meaning to $div(X)$, which I don't fully understand: How does this equation help us to give a geometric meaning of $div (X)$?

We can give an interpretation of divergence from the classic divergence theorem/Gauss theorem from multivariable calculus, which relates the integral of divergence and flux of a vector field. Does the interior derivative generalize/formalize the notion of flux? More precisely, how can we think about interior derivatives geometrically?

When we define the interior derivative of an $n$ form $\omega,$ we basically form an $n-1$ form  $w(X, ......)$ by fixing a vector field slot. Can this contraction by a vector field be interpreted as a"projection of the vector field" along the "surface area element $\partial \omega$"? I know what I am saying is very vague. I would appreciate it if you can help me to understand the notion of interior derivative more concretely/geometrically/intuitively. Thanks so much.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Personally I prefer to call it interior product because it's an operation that does not involve derivatives. Calling it derivative may be misleading from this point of view. 
Indeed in the formula $\int_Mdiv(X)\omega = \int_{\partial M} i_X \omega$ the derivative that you see is really due to Stokes theorem because $d(i_X \omega) = div(X) \omega$ for $n$-forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $M$ and $\partial M$ are compact and oriented.
Equip $M$ with a Riemannian metric, and let $N:\partial M \to TM$ be a *unit* vector field which is normal to $\partial M$ and inward(or outward?) pointing.

Then the Riemannian volume form of $ M$ over the boundary is equal to
$$ \operatorname{vol}_M  = N^\# \wedge \operatorname{vol}_{\partial M}$$
where $N^\# = \langle N, \cdot\rangle $ is the 1-form associated to $N$.
Note that we can extend $N$ to a vector field over the whole $M$ if needed.

What happens when you take the interior product? Over the boundary we have (denoting by $\iota:\partial M \to M$ the inclusion)

$$\iota^*(i_X \operatorname{vol}_M)  = \langle N,X\rangle \operatorname{vol}_{\partial M} \in \Omega^{\dim M -1}(\partial M),$$
note that in general $i_X \operatorname{vol}_M =  \langle N,X\rangle \operatorname{vol}_{\partial M} + rest$ but when you pull it  back to $\partial M$  the rest dies since $\Lambda^{\dim M-1}\partial M $ is spanned by $\operatorname{vol}_{\partial M} $.

From this we see that when we compute $\int_{\partial M} i_X\operatorname{vol}_M = \int_{\partial M} \langle N,X\rangle \operatorname{vol}_{\partial M}$ we are really computing the flow of $X$ along $\partial M$.

Comment: Thanks so much.